# Bloquear pantalla y desbloquear según estado. Laravel y Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Estoy investigando como cambiar el estado de una tabla y que esto me ejecute una condición. Entiendo que a lo mejor lo más apropiado es utilizar cron. Pero me gustaría saber si alguien tiene experiencia llevando a cabo este tipo de proceso y me puede ampliar el panorama.

Hasta el momento logré bloquear la pantalla con css

```
.cargando {
    width: 100%;height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 10000;
    text-align: center;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    opacity:0.6;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);
}
```

Desde vue realizo la inserción de datos y bloqueo la pantalla

```
validarCodigo: function(){
            var IdUser = document.querySelector('meta[name="user-id"]').getAttribute('content');

            var url = '/acceso';
            axios.post(url, {
                usuario_id: IdUser,
                Instagram: this.Instagram,
                email: this.email,
                celular: this.celular,
                codigo: this.codigo,
                estado: this.estado
            });

            if(this.estado == 'DESAPROBADO')
                $("#ocultaEstado").css("display", "block");
            else{
                $("#ocultaEstado").css("display", "none");
            }
        }
```

precisamente en este fragmento:

```
if(this.estado == 'DESAPROBADO')
                    $("#ocultaEstado").css("display", "block");
                else{
                    $("#ocultaEstado").css("display", "none");
                }
```

Hasta ahí bien, pero estoy lejos de comprender bien como sería la manera de cambiar el estado a 'APROBADO' y que la pantalla se desbloque.
Además que intento que sea un simulacro en tiempo real. La pantalla se bloquea y el usuario está esperando en ese momento que un administrador le de acceso.
Agradezco todo tipo de sugerencia.

Comment: Sopongo que si tienes el valor de `this.estado`  podrías usar un `v-if="this.estado == 'DESAPROBADO'"` https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html en vez de css. De todas maneras, sería mas seguro que también lo manejes desde el backend. Y si quieres que suceda en tiempo real podrías implementar websocket https://www.laraveltip.com/utilizando-el-paquete-laravel-websockets-%F0%9F%9B%B0/

Comment: Voy a investigar websocket y con los eventos de Laravel creo que también es una opción viable. Gracias por tu comentario.